# WordPress WooCommerce Add to Cart only adds one product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm quite new to WooCommerce and I can not figure out this one.
I'm creating a custom API (based on user requirement) and I'm letting user login in Laravel using a post request like this:

```
public function login (Request $req)
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $v = \Validator::make($req->all(), [
        'username' => 'required|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);
    if ($v->passes())
    {
        $user = wp_signon(['user_login'=>$req->input("username"),"user_password"=>$req->input("password")],true);
        if (is_wp_error($user) || !is_user_logged_in())
        {
            return response(['success' => false, 'message' => "Invalid Username or Password."], 401);
        }
        $key = md5($user->ID . $user->user_login. (time() + 7200) . $user->email);
        $cookie = wp_generate_auth_cookie($user->ID, (time() + 7200), "auth", $key);
        $store = [
            'user_login'      => $user->data->user_login,
            'user_id'         => $user->data->ID,
            'user_nicename'   => $user->data->user_nicename,
            'user_email'      => $user->data->user_email,
            'user_url'        => $user->data->user_url,
            'user_registered' => $user->data->user_registered,
            'display_name'    => $user->data->display_name,
        ];
        Session::push($cookie, $store);
        WC()->cart->set_session();
        return response(['auth_token' => $cookie, 'success' => true, 'cart'=>WC()->cart->get_cart_for_session(), 'timeout' => 7200], 200);
    }
    return response(['success' => false, 'message' => "Required field(s) missing."], 401);
}
```

Now, whenever I add a product to cart, it only replaces the previous value, and only one item is added to the cart. When I login to my WordPress site and visit the cart, it shows error "Undefined index", while the cart is empty. Here's the code for adding item to cart:

```
public function add($productId)
{
    //WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);
    $cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $productId );
    $prod_in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $cart_id );
    // Add the product only if it's not in the cart already
    if( ! $prod_in_cart ) 
    {
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart($productId,1,0,null,null);
    }
    return response([
        'user'=>WC()->session->get_customer_id(),
        'cart'=>WC()->cart,
    ]);
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong but don't know what. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

**Edit**

If it helps I'm using WooCommerce version 2.3

Comment: `Add the product only if it's not in the cart already`, why do this? if you did not know, `add_to_cart` will update the quantity if the item is already in the cart... but as you are not calling `add_to_cart` if the product is in the cart, the quantity will not update..

Comment: My question is not about the quantity, lets say there are 2 products A and B, if I add A and when I add B, this overwrites A

Answer (score 0):

You have hardcoded the quantity as 1. Here is the function :

```
 WC()->cart->add_to_cart($productId,1,0,null,null);
```

In this function, second parameter is the quantity. So raise the quantity if you want.

```
$qty = 2;
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($productId,$qty,0,null,null);
```

Comment: The problem is not with the quantity, the problem is when you add another product, then it will just replace the existing product. I know the default method is <code>WC()->cart->add_to_cart($productId);</code> but still of no avail. There's something wrong with the session.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've seen your code you're using two different sessions

`WC()->cart->set_session();` &  `WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true)`

I.E Once the user logged in and the second one is while it adds product to the cart. Did you check whether if things are working perfectly without logging in? Other possible problems would be theme integration or either way you've to turn your debug mode **ON** would help you where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've removed the second session, and added product without login, the result is still the same.

Comment: Use this `WC()->cart->set_session();` in the function add(productid) and see if it works?